# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.addStaticHandler(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm running the following example about Java+Spark+SQL.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQL.java

But getting this exception. There's no error during compile-time

How can i avoid this??
Couldn't find anything regarding this exception.
Please Help me.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("JavaSparkSQL");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(ctx);
```

Exception Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI.addStaticHandler(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLTab.<init>(SQLTab.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:79)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:69)
    at org.sun.JavaSparkSQL.main(JavaSparkSQL.java:47)
2015-11-06 18:35:22,834 INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext.logInfo:59 - Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: It should be a version issue. Try switching spark core dependency to a matching version, 1.5.1 in this case.

Comment: It's indeed a version issue! You should always use the same version of all the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you very much..  I solved it by setting version as 1.5.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a version issue! You should always use the same version of all the dependencies.